# How to use awk to read data between all frequent time intervals

Tags: files, awk, timestamps

I have a log file in following format

```
[30/Jan/2015:10:10:30 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 425
[30/Jan/2015:10:11:00 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 261
[30/Jan/2015:10:11:29 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 232
[30/Jan/2015:10:12:00 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 315
[30/Jan/2015:10:12:29 +0000] 12.30.30.204 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 221
[30/Jan/2015:10:12:57 +0000] 12.30.30.182 xff=- reqId=[-] status_check len=- GET /api/getstatus HTTP/1.1 mi=- ec=- 200 218
```

Each line in this log file has response time in the last field & has timestamp in first field. Is there a way in `awk` to read the average response time in all specific intervals? For example, calculating avg response time in every five minutes.

I have tried the following way which is static way of doing it and will give only average of one time interval.

```
$ grep "30/Jan/2015:10:1[0-4]" mylog.log | awk '{resp+=$NF;cnt++;}END{print "Avg:"int(resp/cnt)}'
```

But I need to do it for the whole file for all 5 minutes. Even if I loop the command, how can I pass the date dynamically to the command? Because the log file varies every time and the dates in it.

Or is there any best alternative way to do this other than `awk`? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first close it can be:

```
awk -F"[][ ]*" -v it=300 '{
    sub(":"," ",$2)
    gsub("/"," ",$2)
    "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d
    if (d-f>it) {
        f=d
        if (NR!=1)
            print s/n 
        s=n=""
        }
    n++
    s+=$NF
    }' log.file
```

- `-F"[][ ]*"` used as **F**ields **S**eparator to strip square brackets additionally
- `-v it=300` set variable (interval in seconds)
- `sub,gsub` remove symbols from field to prepare it for `date` command format
- `date` convert field into second (from EPOCH)
- `|getline d` puts above into `d` variable

Comment: I haven't looked into details but the output of your code is `343` and the OP's `grep` solution's is `Avg:278`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging May be you are right (I have not enough input too) but question is to include or not the interval last string. Additionally `10:1[0-4]` is not exact 5-minutes interval.

Comment: @svjn if script gives right data mark your question as `settled`